# Android NDK ALooper_pollOnce() vs ALooper_pollAll()

Tags: android, android-ndk, event-handling

In **Android NDK**, what is the difference between `ALooper_pollOnce()` and `ALooper_pollAll()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These simple specify how many (maximum) callbacks to process from Looper's event queue. As names suggest, `pollAll()` executes all callbacks from the event queue until the data event, error or timeout is encountered. On the other hand, `pollOnce()` returns ALOOPER_POLL_CALLBACK as soon as first callback is executed.

Basically, their relationship can be expressed in the following pseudocode:

```
int ALooper_pollAll(int timeoutMillis, int* outFd, int* outEvents, void** outData) {
  int result;
  do {
    result = ALooper_pollOnce(timeoutMillis, outFd, outEvents, outData);
  } while (result == ALOOPER_POLL_CALLBACK);
  return result;
}
```